# zip a list with space delimited into tuple

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe `df` with a column called `columnList` as str.

```
"1 2,7 8,10 7"
```

Then I converted them to a list as shown :

```
[1 2,7 8,10 7]
```

I want to convert the value inside list to tuple :

```
[(1,2),(7,8),(10,7)]
```

Current code :

```
temp = df['columnList'].str.split(',')
result = list(zip(temp[::2], temp[1::2]))
print(result)
```

I'm getting empty list.

`df` looks like this :

```
column1    columnList
  YY      1 2,7 8,10 7
```

Name: df, dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df.columnsList.apply(lambda x : 
        [tuple(map(int, x.split())) for x in "1 2, 7 8, 10 7".split(",")])
```

output,

```
0    [(1, 2), (7, 8), (10, 7)]
Name: columnsList, dtype: object
```

Comment: It works but the numbers are not converted to float. It is in string

Comment: This works too : `apply(lambda x : [tuple(map(float,x.split())) for x in x.split(",")])` Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `zip` here, just iterate over the list, split each element and store it as a tuple.

```
l = [ '1 2', '7 8', '10 7']
[tuple(int(i) for i in numbers.split()) for numbers in l]

#[(1, 2), (7, 8), (10, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the characters to ints after splitting them, then convert the map object to a tuple:

```
temp = df['columnList'].str.split(',')
result = [tuple(map(int, num.split())) for num in temp]
print(result)
# [(1, 2), (7, 8), (10, 7)]
```